# Go's .(type) Does Something Unexpected When Unmarshaling JSON

Tags: json, go, types

I'm [RTFMing](https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go), specifically the section on Decoding Arbitrary Go Data.  Based on that section, I've written the following test program

```
var f interface{}

json.Unmarshal(
  []byte(`{"Name":"Wednesday","Age":6,"Parents":["Gomez","Morticia"]}`), &f)  

m := f.(map[string]interface{}) 
for k, v := range m {
    switch vv := v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Println(k, "is string", vv)
    case int:
        fmt.Println(k, "is int", vv)
    case []interface{}:
        fmt.Println(k, "is an array:")
        for i, u := range vv {
            fmt.Println(i, u)
        }
    default:
        fmt.Println(k, "is of a type I don't know how to handle")
        fmt.Println("    Type Is:", vv)
    }
}
```

That is, I declare a variable with an empty interface type.  Per the docs, I

> use a type assertion to access f's underlying map[string]interface{}:

Then, I use `range` to do a for loop over the map's key/value pairs.  If the value is a string, int, or []interface, the program says so.  If that value is another type, (the default case), the program says I don't know how to handle it.  This is almost verbatim code from the manual.

The program produces the following output.

```
Name is string Wednesday
Age is of a type I don't know how to handle
    Type Is: 6
Parents is an array:
0 Gomez
1 Morticia
```

That is -- it correctly identifies the types of strings and arrays -- for for some reason it seems like the type of the parsed `6` isn't and `int` -- it's 6.

So -- I guess my question is either *why does `v.(type)` return the actual number oinstead of `int` here **or** my question is *why is that the wrong question*?

Comment: JSON doesn't have integer numbers, only floats.

Comment: @JimB D'oh -- guess I better RTFJsonSpec as well.  Can confirm -- those values come through typed as `float64`.  Happy to accept an answer with the same info in the answers section.  Also, if anyone knows how I might flag the team behind https://blog.golang.org/json-and-go to update their code sample, that would be rad.

Comment: You can probably file an issue in the main issue tracker, or simply mention it on the mailing list ;)

Comment: The `default` case in a type switch is a special case; the variable is not of the specified type (since there is no specified type).  To see the true type, consider using `fmt.Printf("%T", v)`.

Comment: Now fixed https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/blog/+/71930 it might take a while to show up on live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON numbers are double precision floats, so the default type go uses is `float64`. You can see the defaults listed in the [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) documentation.